# Retrieving D.images['some-image'].frame_duration always returns 1

Tags: python

Given the following code sample in a headless instance of blender:

```
movie = I.load(green_screen_img.filepath)
duration = movie.frame_duration
print(duration)
```

Blender console will print 1 for the duration.

However if I print some other info about the movie file beforehand, like so:

```
movie = I.load(green_screen_img.filepath)
print(movie.resolution)
duration = movie.frame_duration
print(duration)
```

Blender console will correctly print the correct duration, 272

I really would like to understand this behavior and would be interested if anyone can clarify what is going on here.

Comment: Had a quick look and came across same behaviour,  If I.has_data is False the duration is incorrectly reported as 1.  Calling I.update() after load had the same effect for me as your example printing resolution.  The example file I used was a mkv.